# Java multithreading: a good way to notify the consumer threads that all the producer threads have finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a fairly simple producer/consumer-scenario: I have some threads that deliver data to a monitor, and other threads that await data in the monitor, remove it and deliver the data to another monitor. At a certain point, the producers wille all have delivered their last data to the monitor. After the consumers have consumed the last data in the monitor, they need to be told not await more data from the monitor. To make this run as it should, the consumer threads need to get notified when the last producer thread has produced it's last bit of data, and there is no more data due. I am sure there are multiple ways to do this. As of now, the monitor counts the number of active produer threads, and when a producer thread finishes, it tells the monitor so. I am very curios though what the more elegant approach to this would be.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to let each producer send a `poison pill` where consumer would keep a count of the poison pills received so far and compare it with the number of producers.

```
 class Consumer{
   final int numOfProducers;
   int poisonPillsReceived;

   void run(){
     while(true){
        Object obj = queue.poll();
        if(isPoisonPill(obj)){
          poisonPillsReceived++;
        }

        if(numOfProducers == poisonPillsReceived){
         break;
        }else{
          ....
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the poison pill have to be processed by each consumer, not just one?

Comment: if you sharing using a single queue then it is one consumer allowed, otherwise you have to broadcast to different queues.

Comment: Yes but the question implies there is a single queue being used by multiple producers and multiple consumers. Your idea is ok but the OP may have some extra work to do to get what he wants